# How does GetProfileString function look for values in the registry?

Tags: vba, winapi

I was trying to get the default printer through VBA and I came across the Windows API `GetProfileString` function:
[GetProfileString documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724366%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

On one website I found a working example that retrieves the printer name:

```
returnedChars = GetProfileString("Windows", ByVal "device", vbNullString, printerName, Len(printerName))
```

The site I linked states that on Windows Server 2003, Windows XP and Windows 2000 (and later versions as well, I assume - the documentation probably isn't up-to-date) the values that `GetProfileString` return may be taken from the registry if certain conditions are met. I opened the Registry Editor and found the correct section - `...\IniFileMapping\win.ini\Windows`. To my surprise, there is no key named `device`. I re-read the documentation a couple of times, but it didn't help. I don't have a corresponding section in my `win.ini` file.

Can anyone explain how this function exactly works? It looks like it could come in handy in numerous situations, so it would be nice to know how to use it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is one giant backwards compatibility shim. The idea is for legacy code to continue working by picking up values that were moved to the registry when Windows moved from 16-bit to 32-bit.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724366.aspx) makes this pretty clear:

> **Note**  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit Windows-based applications, therefore this function should not be called from server code. Applications should store initialization information in the registry.

The message is clear. Do not use this function.

You ask how the function works, when it reads from the registry. That is covered in some detail by the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724366.aspx) and I don't think there's much to be gained by trying to re-phrase that documentation.

> It would be nice to know how to use it properly.

Use the function properly by never calling it!